# Firebase update DB at regular intervals

Tags: android, ios, google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an app using Firebase. As per my requirement, I have to reset the entries in Firebase DB at some regular intervals (for example, every 12 hours, I have to reset the existing entries in Firebase).

Is there any way to do this? Also I don't want to do this in App side.
Is it possible to integrate Google App Engine with Firebase? If yes, please provide any useful links.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definitely do this.  I did something similar in a project of mine that copies data from a third party into a database periodically.

The basic steps to get set up can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-app-engine-flexible).  Basically:

1. Set up an app engine instance (it can even be your in Firebase project, backed by a GCP project)
2. Use the Firebase server SDK to implement a servlet that does what you want.
3. Set up a [repeating cron job](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron) to invoke it as often as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Write your periodic update processing using the [Firebase Server SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/server/start) and run it on a server of your choice.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But we don't know whether this could be useful or not.